# WSO2 APIM custom error messages removed after restart

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I added some custom error messages to the APIM according to documentation https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/troubleshooting/error-handling/ - I created custom file  in
`<API-M_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences` and added references to that file in some of the default files in that directory (so that it is called to transform error message).

Everything seemed to be working just fine until the restart of WSO2 - after that, changes made to default files were present, but the custom file was removed, so that custom error message handling didn't work.

I resolved this by adding non-removable attribute (`chattr +i`) to the file, but I wonder is there other, more elegant way to prevent the file from being deleted every time restart is being made?

Answer (score 1):

There are 'template' files placed in: `<API-M_HOME>/repository/resources/apim-synapse-config`. Maybe, those files are overriding files in the `../synapse-configs/default/` location.

Second thing, which came on my mind, is using specific High Avability scenario.  Where artifacts are shared files in system as the content synchronization mechanism, it can override local changes.

Answer (score 1):

At the startup gateway removes these files. You can add the following configuration to the deployment.toml and place the file in the sequence directory.

Sample Config:

```
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
apis = ["api1.xml","api2.xml"]
endpoints = ["endpoint1.xml"]
sequences = ["post_with_nobody.xml"]
local-entries = ["file.xml"]
```

For your case:

```
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
sequences = ["name_of_the_file.xml"]
```

Refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/#configure-the-gateway-nodes